# Как сформировать перечисление через запятую и точку в конце?

Tags: pascal

Мне нужно в конце вывода, после последнего символа, писать точку в конце. Например:

Вывод, который меня сейчас:

```
а, а, у, ю,
```

А я хочу так:

```
а, а, у, ю.
```

Как это можно сделать?

Код:

```
{uses crt;}
var
  b,s: string;
  q,i: integer;
begin
  b := ('аеёиоуыэюя');
  writeln('введите текст с точкой в конце');
  read(s);
  for i := 1 to 10 do begin
    q := 0;
    repeat
      q := q+1;
      if s[q] = b[i] then
        write(b[i], ', ');
    until s[q] = ('.');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Лайфхак (не всегда работает, поэтому комментарием): после вывода всех символов сделать (для вашего случая) `write(#8, #8, '.');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не вдаваясь в детали.
first - указывает что это первый выводимый символ и запятую перед ним не надо. Ну а точку уже в самом конце

```
{uses crt;}
var b,s:string;
var q,i:integer;
var first:boolean;
begin
b:=('аеёиоуыэюя');
writeln('введите текст с точкой в конце');
read(s);
for i:=1 to 10 do begin
q:=0;
first:=true;
repeat
q:=q+1;
if s[q]=b[i] then begin
 if not first then write(', ');
 write(b[i]);
 first:=false;
end;
until s[q]=('.');
end;
write('.');
end.
```

Comment: Интересное решение. Но, правда, не понимаю, почему на выводе некоторые буквы не разделяются запятой?
Вводил: машина, ракета, человек.
Получил: а, а, а, ае, е, еио.
Их можно разделить?

Comment: да, пожалуй... first:=true; надо перенести выше. перед первым циклом

Answer (score 0):

Проверяй: 
( но цикл for мне не нравится твой)

```
 {uses crt;}
    var b,s:string;
    var q,i:integer;
    begin
  b := ('аеёиоуыэюя');
 writeln('введите текст с точкой в конце');
read(s);

for i:=1 to 10 do 
begin
q:=0;
repeat
q:=q+1;
if i<10 then
       begin
           if s[q]=b[i] then
               write(b[i], ', ');
       end
   else 
       begin
          if s[q]=b[i] then 
             write(b[i], '. ');
   end
   until s[q]=('.');
end;
end.
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Мне в конце нужна точка, а там запятая.Я саму логику не могу придумать для этого, чтобы вывести в конце точку, а не запятую